# Why do CSS styles conflict each other even after using CSS module in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, sass

[image]

I have 1 css file and 1 scss file which are appStyle.module.scss and cartList.module.css respectively as we can see above. The css file is addressed only to CartList and CartShow components. However, the css style is still applied to other components unintentionally.

[image]

Abvove image shows the Header, ProductList, ProductShow, Footer components which are affected by the css file. I tried to see what will appear in my screen if I empty the css file and this how it looks in my screen:

[image]

The scss styling is applied entirely to the components. So how can I fix this problem?

Comment: Could you put together a reproducible example that can reproduce your problem? Like a codesanbox or GitHub Repo

Comment: I think I figured out the problem. The problem is both css and scss style some specific html tags and since css module doesn't support html tag, the html tag styling becomes globally scoped. Any idea to get rid of this issue? Thanks in advance.